# Implementation of a recursive tree function to gather highest level nodes

Tags: python, oop, recursion, tree

I am trying to build a tree structure where I could select any node and the lowest corresponding children would be returned into a list. For example, if I select node 1, I get a list containing [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. If Chose node 2, I get [5, 6, 7]. If I chose node 4, I only get [9]. The criteria to define the nodes to be aggregated is that they don't have any children. The tree structure representation is the following:

[image: Tree structure representation]

So far, I tried to implement it:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.children = []
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)

    @property
    def ChildElements(self):
       return [Node(a) for a in self.children]

    @property
    def GetValue(self):
        return self.value

def node_recurse_generator(node):
    yield node.value
    for n in node.ChildElements:
        yield from node_recurse_generator(n)
```

Then I define a small tree structure:

```
a = Node('a')
b = Node('b')
c = Node('c')
d = Node('d')

a.add_child([b, c])
c.add_child(d)

list(node_recurse_generator(a))

##Yields ['a', [b, c]]
```

Maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: In the example, if you chose 4 shouldn't the output be [9]? I am not sure I understood how it works.

Comment: Yes Indeed it was a typo